# How to define remote Ray function on the driver instead?

Tags: python, ray

I have nested remote Ray functions defined inside a class as methods to the class. The code runs properly but I get the following warning...

> WARNING import_thread.py:131 -- The remote function 'process.d2' has
> been exported 100 times. It's possible that this warning is
> accidental, but this may indicate that the same remote function is
> being defined repeatedly from within many tasks and exported to all of
> the workers. This can be a performance issue and can be resolved by
> defining the remote function on the driver instead. See
> https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/6240 for more discussion.

I referred to the github link but unfortunately I couldn't make sense of what to do here.

My code is structured like so...

```
class SomeClass():
@ray.remote
def main(self):
    while True:
        tasks = []
        for _ in range(10):
            tasks.append(ray.get(self.d1.remote(self)))
        ray.get(tasks)

@ray.remote
def d1(self):
    for _ in range(10):
        self.d2.remote(self)

@ray.remote
def d2(self):
    for _ in range(10):
        self.d3.remote(self)

@ray.remote
def d3(self):
    self.do_something()
```

This is just an example. The reason for doing all these nested remote functions in the actual code is because each nested function access a different object from the same class attributes. I have main defined as a remote function as well because I am running the whole process in parallel with some other code.

How should I go about redefining the class methods on the driver instead? Would they need to be defined before I create an instance of the class?